# Cakephp URL Rewriting and redirection

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting

I had an URL www.domain.com/example and I changed it to www.domain.com/example2/example3. It is working fine. But when I manually access old URL, it is accessible but what I need is it should be redirected to new URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Router::redirect(
    '/example',
    '/example2/example3',
    array('persist' => true)
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing

http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Router.html#_redirect

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is a .htaccess file in example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    (.*) http://domain.com/example2/example3 [R]
</IfModule>
```

And remove all your code from example.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

> if www.domain.com/example uses controller => example and action =>
>   index

then use:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/example1/example2/*',
    array('controller' => 'example', 'action' => 'index'),
    array('persist' => true)
);
```